# How to retrieve a Customer from Stripe account using PHP Cashier with stripe_id?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I need to retrieve a customer email that have been created using embedded pricing table on Stripe. Documentation shows that you can retrieve a customer from database using the following code:

```php
use Laravel\Cashier\Cashier;
 
$user = Cashier::findBillable($stripeId);
```

But what I need is to retrieve a customer that does exist only in Stripe but not on my local database using his stripe_id. Is it possible to do this with Cashier?

Comment: SO how do you know the `stripe_id` if the customer does not exist on your database?

Comment: Using webhooks, I'll be getting the stripe_id. But not the email related to that stripe_id in customer.subscription.updated event

Comment: I'm not familiar with laravel-cashier, but you can always use the Stripe PHP library and retrieve the Customer that way. https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/retrieve?lang=php

Comment: @codename_duchess I found this https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/retrieve but your solution is a much more fit thanks.